# What is the correct way of replacing the first convolution layer of a TensorFlow model (for adapting the number of input channels)?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to replace the first convolution layer of a TensorFlow model in order to adapted to a different number of input channels. I want to use some pre-trained weights on Imagenet to speed up the training of a model that instead takes 4 input channels, rather than the RGB channels of ImageNet.

In order to do that I want to replace the first convolution layer of the pre-trained model with a convolution layer that goes from 4 to the number of channels of the second convolution (64). The reason that I want to do this is that to me it seems a more natural way to use the ImageNet weights than adding a conv layer before the pre-trained model which goes from 4 input channels to 3 channels and then just use the pre-trained model as it is.

I tried to use the fuctional API to select just a part of the model, but it returns an error about a discontinuity  in the graph between the input layer and the rest of the network.I also tried some other ways, but quite similar to the one posted and I still get the same error every time. Chopping off the end of the model seems much easier than doing the same with the initial layers, since every layer keeps a reference to the one before through the graph.

```py
    idx_first_layer_to_copy = 2 if isinstance(pretrained_model.layers[0], tf.keras.layers.InputLayer) else 1
    first_layer_to_copy = pretrained_model.layers[idx_first_layer_to_copy]
    compatible_part_of_pretrained_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        inputs=first_layer_to_copy.input,
        outputs=pretrained_model.output
    )
    adapted_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, None, n_input_channels)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(first_layer_to_copy.filters,
                               first_layer_to_copy.kernel_size,
                               activation='relu',
                               padding='same'),
        compatible_part_of_pretrained_model,
    ])
```

and this is the error stack

```py
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_ TestAdaptModelToInputChannelsIfNecessary.test_input_pass_without_raising_errors_through_model _

self = <tests.test_prepare_model.test_prepare_model.TestAdaptModelToInputChannelsIfNecessary object at 0x7f803a0ebaf0>

    def test_input_pass_without_raising_errors_through_model(self):
        """Test that a previous incompatible tensor can pass through the adapted model without raising erros."""
        # arrange
        n_input_channels = 4
        tensor_incompatible_with_pretrained_model = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(32, 32, n_input_channels), minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=42
        )
    
        pretrained_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='sigmoid')
        ])
    
>       adapted_model = adapt_model_to_input_channels_if_necessary(pretrained_model, n_input_channels)

test_prepare_model.py:43: 

inputs = [<tf.Tensor 'conv2d/Relu:0' shape=(None, None, None, 16) dtype=float32>]
outputs = [<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_2/Sigmoid:0' shape=(None, None, None, 1) dtype=float32>]

    def _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs):
      """Validates a network's topology and gather its layers and nodes.
    
      Arguments:
        inputs: List of input tensors.
        outputs: List of outputs tensors.
    
      Returns:
        A tuple `(nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth)`.
        - nodes: list of Node instances.
        - nodes_by_depth: dict mapping ints (depth) to lists of node instances.
        - layers: list of Layer instances.
        - layers_by_depth: dict mapping ints (depth) to lists of layer instances.
    
      Raises:
        ValueError: In case the network is not valid (e.g. disconnected graph).
      """
      # "depth" is number of layers between output Node and the Node.
      # Nodes are ordered from inputs -> outputs.
      nodes_in_decreasing_depth, layer_indices = _build_map(outputs)
      network_nodes = {
          _make_node_key(node.layer.name, node.layer._inbound_nodes.index(node))
          for node in nodes_in_decreasing_depth
      }
    
      nodes_depths = {}  # dict {node: depth value}
      layers_depths = {}  # dict {layer: depth value}
    
      for node in reversed(nodes_in_decreasing_depth):
        # If the depth is not set, the node has no outbound nodes (depth 0).
        depth = nodes_depths.setdefault(node, 0)
    
        # Update the depth of the corresponding layer
        previous_depth = layers_depths.get(node.layer, 0)
        # If we've seen this layer before at a higher depth,
        # we should use that depth instead of the node depth.
        # This is necessary for shared layers that have inputs at different
        # depth levels in the graph.
        depth = max(depth, previous_depth)
        layers_depths[node.layer] = depth
        nodes_depths[node] = depth
    
        # Update the depth of inbound nodes.
        # The "depth" of a node is the max of the depths
        # of all nodes it is connected to + 1.
        for node_dep in node.parent_nodes:
          previous_depth = nodes_depths.get(node_dep, 0)
          nodes_depths[node_dep] = max(depth + 1, previous_depth)
    
      # Handle inputs that are not connected to outputs.
      # We do not error out here because the inputs may be used to compute losses
      # and metrics.
      for input_t in inputs:
        input_layer = input_t._keras_history[0]
        if input_layer not in layers_depths:
          layers_depths[input_layer] = 0
          layer_indices[input_layer] = -1
          nodes_depths[input_layer._inbound_nodes[0]] = 0
          network_nodes.add(_make_node_key(input_layer.name, 0))
    
      # Build a dict {depth: list of nodes with this depth}
      nodes_by_depth = collections.defaultdict(list)
      for node, depth in nodes_depths.items():
        nodes_by_depth[depth].append(node)
    
      # Build a dict {depth: list of layers with this depth}
      layers_by_depth = collections.defaultdict(list)
      for layer, depth in layers_depths.items():
        layers_by_depth[depth].append(layer)
    
      # Get sorted list of layer depths.
      depth_keys = list(layers_by_depth.keys())
      depth_keys.sort(reverse=True)
    
      # Set self.layers ordered by depth.
      layers = []
      for depth in depth_keys:
        layers_for_depth = layers_by_depth[depth]
        # Network.layers needs to have a deterministic order:
        # here we order them by traversal order.
        layers_for_depth.sort(key=lambda x: layer_indices[x])
        layers.extend(layers_for_depth)
    
      # Get sorted list of node depths.
      depth_keys = list(nodes_by_depth.keys())
      depth_keys.sort(reverse=True)
    
      # Check that all tensors required are computable.
      # computable_tensors: all tensors in the graph
      # that can be computed from the inputs provided.
      computable_tensors = set()
      for x in inputs:
        computable_tensors.add(id(x))
    
      layers_with_complete_input = []  # To provide a better error msg.
      for depth in depth_keys:
        for node in nodes_by_depth[depth]:
          layer = node.layer
          if layer and not node.is_input:
            for x in nest.flatten(node.keras_inputs):
              if id(x) not in computable_tensors:
>               raise ValueError('Graph disconnected: '
                                 'cannot obtain value for tensor ' + str(x) +
                                 ' at layer "' + layer.name + '". '
                                 'The following previous layers '
                                 'were accessed without issue: ' +
                                 str(layers_with_complete_input))
E               ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "conv2d". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```